# How to set the property of element of a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which returns List (Role has Id,Name) and I need to convert that into a List (MyRole has Id,Name,selected)

```
var y = x.Roles.Select(r => new MyRole(r.Name, r.Id, false));
```

Ok, so far so good.  But now I need to change the "selected" property for element with ID=123 to be true.  Kind of stumped on the linq-iest way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

```
var y = x.Roles.Select(r => new MyRole(r.Name, r.Id, r.ID == 123));
```

This comes at the cost of evaluating the equality at each iteration, but if you absolutely want to have a LINQ query that sort of very small performance hit probably doesn't bother you too much!

Answer (score 4):

Linq if for *querying* not *updating*.  You need to "locate" the right object then update it just like you normally would:

```
var y = x.Roles.Select(r => new MyRole(r.Name, r.Id, false));
var y123 = y.Single(r => r.Id == 123);  // equivalent to Where(...).Single()
y123.Selected = true;
```

Or you can bake it into your projection with a conditional statement:

```
var y = x.Roles.Select(r => new MyRole(r.Name, r.Id, (r.Id == 123) ? true : false));
// the ? true : false is unnecessary, just adding it here to illustrate the check
```